# update security certificate on unsupported operating system

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I am using an old Macbook Pro (13 inch, Mid 2014) with Version 10.11.6 of the OS. The OS can't be updated anymore.

For the most part, the computer is still very functional with two caveats. I'm guessing and hoping these two caveats are related (and can be solved by the same solution)

First, I cannot visit any .dev domains whatsoever.[trying to visit a .dev domain name](https://imgur.com/FFtEsAF) There must be something unique about .dev domains that is stopping me from visiting them.

Second, when I visit non .dev domains, I get a "your connection is not private warning" [trying to visit math.stackexchange.com](https://imgur.com/nBa3ikh)

Keeping in mind that I cannot update my OS, is there anything I can do about this problem?

Comment: A 2014 MPB can run Big Sur macOS 11.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for the tip. My MBP does not give me the option to download and install MacOS 11 and I spoke to Apple on the phone about it and they didn't mention it as being available for me.

Comment: It won't do - you've left it far too long. Basically, there's been a major update every year since the Mac was new - which have been ignored. If you ignore it long enough, it never asks again. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/85275

Comment: Right now, I am trying to fix the problem I posted about without trying to update OS ( which Apple has told me is not possible to do.)

Comment: Your OS is too old to understand the modern certificate requirements.

Comment: @Tetsujin ah, thank you for clarifying. But how come I can visit some websites but not others?

Comment: it will depend on what certificate structure they're using. You're using an OS [& presumably browser] almost 10 years out of date.